# update a db sqlite no such table error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with the db i created. It doesn't find The table "Journal"
I supposed that it's an update of db problem cos i can't see any problem in create script.I'm working with a real device and i don't know how to completly remove the db from the device so it creates the db. I tried to uninstall the app but nothing changed.
Here's the code and the error :

> No such table Journal

```
private static final String CREATE_BDD = "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_CONTACTBL + " ("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_NOM + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_NUM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_NUM_RECH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_PREFIX +" TEXT NOT NULL);"
            + "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_JOURNAL + " ("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_DATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + COL_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            + "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_GROUPES + " ("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_NOM + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            + "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_FAVORITES + " ("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_ID_MSG + " INTEGER);"
            + "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_CONTACTWL + " ("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_NOM + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_GROUPE + " INTEGER, "+ COL_NUM +" TEXT NOT NULL);";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //on crée la table à partir de la requête écrite dans la variable CREATE_BDD
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //On peut faire ce qu'on veut ici moi j'ai décidé de supprimer la table et de la recréer
    //comme ça lorsque je change la version les id repartent de 0
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTBL + ";");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_JOURNAL + ";");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GROUPES + ";");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTWL + ";");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FAVORITES + ";");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

what causes the error :

```
try {
    journalList = notificationsDAO.getAllNotifications();
} catch (SQLiteException e){
    errorMessage=e.getMessage();
    notificationsDAO.close();
    return false;
}

public ArrayList<NotificationJournal> getAllNotifications(){
    //Récupère dans un Cursor les valeurs correspondant à un livre contenu dans la BDD (ici on sélectionne le livre grâce à son titre)
    Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE_JOURNAL,new String[]{"*"},null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursorToList(c);
}
```

Need help to swipe the data and to have my real db. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `execSQL()` to execute a single SQL statement. Anything after the first `;` is not executed.

Split your string containing multiple `CREATE TABLE` statements to separate `execSQL()` calls.

Comment: Thanks i will try this. So it's really a script error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
@Override
public synchronized void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sqls[] = CREATE_BDD.split(";");
    for (String sql : sqls)
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);
}
```